# getting information inside the division php javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

When I clicked the button "**click me**", the selected ID will print to the `var divtest` then fade out in the `<div id="container">` and when I clicked the another button "**click me**" it only gets the first id but all I want is the second id in the database to show. If I try to remove the selected description it will go back to the container of ID description.

My database sample.

```
ID Description    
1    Hello
2    Hi
3    Thank You
```

This is my sample code.

```
<?php 
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","dblaquaresort") or die("Failed to Connect");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblsample";
    $query =  mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while ($sample = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) 
    {
    ?><div id="container">
    <label id="ID">ID: <?php echo $sample['ID']; ?></label>
    <label id="Description">Description: <?php echo $sample['Description']; ?></label>
    <button type="button" id="more_fields" onclick="add_fields();">Click me</button> </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>

    <div id="room_fileds">
     <div>
       <div class="content">
         <?php
              function not_empty_string($s) 
              {
                return $s !== " ";
              }
              $pieces = array_filter(explode(",", "Test"),'not_empty_string');
              foreach ($pieces as $piece) 
              {
               $test_stinga = array_filter(explode("-", $piece),'not_empty_string');
               $test_stinga=preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $test_stinga);
              }
             ?>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
            <script>
                var room = 1;
                var wrapper = $(".testtt");
                function add_fields() 
                {
                room++;
                var objTo = document.getElementById('room_fileds');
                var ID = document.getElementById('ID').innerHTML;
                var Desc = document.getElementById('Description').innerHTML;
                var divtest = document.createElement("div");
                 divtest.innerHTML = '<div class="label">TEST ' + room + ':</div> <div class="content"><span><p class="form-inline">Testing: '+ ID +'</span><span>Description: ' + Desc + '</span><button class="remove"> Remove</button></p></div>';
                   objTo.appendChild(divtest)
                        }
                     $('#room_fileds').on("click",".remove", function(e)
                     {
                     $(this).parents().eq(5).remove();
                     })
                </script>
```

This is the output I want.

```
Div Container
ID: 1 Description: Hello <button>click me</button>
ID: 2 Description: Hi <button>click me</button>
ID: 3 Description: Thank You <button>click me</button>
```

If i click the ID = 2.

```
Div Container
ID: 1 Description: Hello <button>click me</button>
ID: 3 Description: Thank You <button>click me</button>

Divtest
ID: 2 Description: Hi <button>Remove</button>
```

If I Click the remove it will go back in **Div Container**.

```
ID: 1 Description: Hello <button>click me</button>
ID: 2 Description: Hi <button>click me</button>
ID: 3 Description: Thank You <button>click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating the same `ID` for the HTML elements the 3 times in this loop:

```
while ($sample = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
```

This element `<div id="container">` will be 3 times according to your example, you need to make each `id` different. You can use the `Id` of the row your fetching from the database so you can do something like:

```
 while ($sample = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) 
    {
    ?><div id="container_<?php echo $sample['ID']; ?>">
    <label id="ID_<?php echo $sample['ID']; ?>">ID: <?php echo $sample['ID']; ?></label>
    ......
```

so when you add this `<?php echo $sample['ID']; ?>` to your html ids like: `id="container_<?php echo $sample['ID']; ?>"` you create unique ids for the elements, you need to do this to have unique html ids.

Now you need to modify your javascript function:

```
function add_fields()
```

you shall make it gets a parameter, like:

```
function add_fields(id)
```

and you can pass the id of the row, so it'll be:

```
<button type="button" id="more_fields_<?php echo $sample['ID']; ?>" onclick="add_fields(\"<?php echo $sample['ID']; ?>\");">Click me</button> </div>
```

and you'll need to modify the content of the function, to work with that `id`:

```
  function add_fields(id) 
  {
     room++;
     var objTo = document.getElementById('room_fileds_'+id);
     .....
```

I hope this helps.